# Toggling Classes and Slide Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for the best way to solve this problem, here is my html:

```
            <div class="section group">
                <article class="col span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>Design</h3>
                    <div id="design" class="circle">
                        <div class="icon icon-pencil"></div>
                    </div>                              
                </article>
                <article class="col span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>Development</h3>
                    <div id="development" class="circle">
                        <div class="icon icon-code"></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="col span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>Branding</h3>
                    <div id="branding" class="circle">
                        <div class="icon icon-tag"></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="col span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>Mobile</h3>
                    <div id="mobile" class="circle">
                        <div class="icon icon-mobile-phone"></div>
                    </div>
                </article>  
            </div>
            <div id="services">
                <div class="design">
                    some text
                </div>
                <div class="development">
                    some text                   
                </div>
                <div class="branding">
                    some text                   
                </div>
                <div class="mobile">
                    some text                   
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$('#about .circle').click(function(e) {
    if ($('#about .circle').hasClass('enabled')) {
        $('.design, .development, .branding, .mobile').slideUp();
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("enabled")) {
        $(this).removeClass("enabled");
    } else {            
        $('#about .circle').removeClass("enabled"); 
        $(this).addClass("enabled");
        $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown();
    }
});
```

I just want it to toggle the classes on the text below the circles when you click the circles. I want it to slide up and down but if you click another circle i want it to scroll up then finish animation and then down. At the moment it slides them both at the same time. I know you can pass a complete function to slide up to make it only slide down when its complete but it didnt work.

If anyone knows a better way let me know!

Thanks

Comment: @BeatAlex a wrapper around all of this sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is a visible element that needs to be hidden:

- If there is one then hide it and show the next element when the hide animation completes
- If there is none then the next element

Rough outline of the code:

```
// hide elements on page load
$("#services > div").hide();
$("#about .circle").click(function (e) {
    var classToShow = "." + $(this).attr("id");
    // do nothing if element is already visible
    if ($("#services > div" + classToShow + ":visible").length) {
        return;
    }
    // stop existing animations
    if ($("#services > div:animated").length) {
        $("#services > div:animated").stop();
    }
    // if an element needs to be hidden
    if ($("#services > div:visible").length) {
        // hide it
        $("#services > div:visible").slideUp("slow", function () {
            // show next element when first animation completes
            $("#services > div" + classToShow).slideDown("slow");
        });
    } else {
        // just show next element
        $("#services > div" + classToShow).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/A3Z46/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class target to the service elements like

```
<div id="services">
    <div class="design target">some text</div>
    <div class="development target">some text</div>
    <div class="branding target">some text</div>
    <div class="mobile target">some text</div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $targets = $('#services .target');
    var $cirlces = $('#about .circle').click(function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('enabled');
        var $target = $('.' + this.id).stop(true).slideDown();
        $targets.not($target).stop(true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JV78A/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
        //First time it has to SlideUp
        $('#about .circle').addClass("enabled");

        //Click event
        $('#about .circle').click(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $("." + $this[0].id + "").slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $this.toggleClass('enabled');
            });               
        });
```